# Ionin 3 - NavParams getting undefined error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular6

I am trying to call the reddit api to get and store a list then iterate over it in html, which works, but when I pass the data for a single item in list by adding through Navparams the details page gets undefined error, the data however is accessible in the onClick method definition in list typescript file

Here is the code:
home.html

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item  *ngFor="let post of posts">
      <ion-thumbnail (click)="onPostClicked(post)" item-start>
        <img [src]="post.data.thumbnail">
      </ion-thumbnail>
      <h2>{{post.data.title}}</h2>
      <p>{{post.data.author}}</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

home.ts

```js
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { PostPage } from '../post/post';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

@Injectable()
export class HomePage {
  posts: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get("https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/top/.json?limit=10&sort=hot")
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.posts = data.data.children;
      })
  }

  onPostClicked(post: any) {
    let singlePost = post;
    console.log(singlePost);
    this.navCtrl.push(PostPage, singlePost);
  }

}
```

post.html - which I've left with just a template

```html
<!--
  Generated template for the PostPage page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
-->
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title></ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

</ion-content>
```

page.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';



/**
 * Generated class for the PostPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-post',
  templateUrl: 'post.html',
})
export class PostPage {


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    let post = this.navParams.get("singlePost");
    console.log(post);
    
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad PostPage');
  }

}
```

Comment: this.navCtrl.push(PostPage,{singlePost:singlePost});

Comment: You can try above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the variable in the `navCtrl.push()` by giving the vaiable name and the value like

```
this.navCtrl.push(pageName, {varname : value } );
```

So, 
Your method should be

```
onPostClicked(post: any) {
    let singlePost = post;
    console.log(singlePost);
    this.navCtrl.push(PostPage, {singlePost : singlePost} );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have value get properly,

```
console.log(singlePost); //From this line
```

Here is an example you have to modify little bit,

Set Params,

```
 onPostClicked(post: any) {
    let singlePost = post;
    console.log(singlePost);
    if(singlePost){  
        this.navCtrl.push(PostPage, {'singlePost',singlePost});
    }
  }
```

Get Params

```
 let post = this.navParams.get("singlePost");
 console.log(post);
```

Then now its printing Properly.

Comment: isn't `if(singlePost)` equivalent to `if(singlePost!=null && singlePost!=undefined)`?

Answer (score 0):

[Working Solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-navparms)

HTML:

home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

 <button ion-button (click)="navigateToOtherPage(posts)">Navigate</button>
</ion-content>
```

contact.html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Contact
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div>
    Name: {{data.name}}
  </div>
  <div>
    Name: {{data.age}}
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

TS:

home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {ContactPage} from '../contact/contact';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  posts: object = {
    name: 'UnluckyAj',
    age: '20'
  }

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }

  navigateToOtherPage(params){
    this.navCtrl.push(ContactPage, {params: params});
  }

}
```

contact.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-contact',
  templateUrl: 'contact.html'
})
export class ContactPage {
  data: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
  public prm : NavParams) {
    this.getDataFromNavigation();
  }
  getDataFromNavigation(){
    this.data = this.prm.get('params')
  }

}
```